# how to define null in an oozie workflow

Tags: oozie

How can I configure an optional input path in oozie job.properties file? So I want the default value for that input path to be null and I will set that path when running the oozie job using -D parameter.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Oozie converts the configuration into an Properties instance which underneath uses HashTable which does not allow null as value. Though I believe you can submit the workflow with a dummy value and later while running the workflow update the value to actual one using -D <key=value>. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks YoungHobbit, your explanation was very helpful.

Comment: On the other hand, you might try to set a `<property>`with an EL expression that checks whether that parameter is `empty` and forces a default value in that case, cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html  Although I am not sure that Oozie support of EL is good enough to support that on an parameter name that is not already in the hash table.

Comment: May be you can try this: Set the value as single whitespace string, that should get converted to `null` and should the purpose. PS: I have not tested/tried this. Thanks.